# Tweepy: Trying to fetch 3200 tweets from a public twitter account

Tags: python, pandas, api, twitter, tweepy

With the python code below I tried to fetch 3200 tweets from a public twitter profile, but so far I only get different amounts of tweets which are way less than the maximum of 3200 tweets and I can't really understand the problem. Can someone please explain me what I am doing wrong here?

```
import tweepy
import json
import pandas as pd

consumer_key = "xxx"
consumer_secret = "xxx"
access_token = "xxx"
access_token_secret = "xxx"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True) 

results=[]

timeline = tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name='@realDonaldTrump', tweet_mode="extended").items()

for status in timeline:
    data = (
    status.user.id,
    status.user.screen_name,
    status.user.name,
    status.full_text,
    status.created_at,
    status.lang)
    results.append(data)

cols = "user_id screen_name name text date lang".split()
df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=cols)
```

Comment: This tool may help: https://github.com/pauldotknopf/twitter-dump